# SQL Server procedure function value to used in select statement

Tags: sql-server, function, select, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure `p_calc_member_fee @id` to get `member_fee` for the person and stored in a `temp` table.

And then I need to extract the value in a select statement because I need to pass in the member id to get the member fee, so I created a function named `fn_get_member_fee` to call the procedure to return the `member_fee`. But it seems like I cannot call the function by using

```
select fn_get_member_fee (@member.id) from member
```

I got the below error, please kindly help, thank you

> Msg 557, Level 16, State 2, Line 39
>   Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Comment: Can you show fn_get_member_fee ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute SP from function. There is one exception but it is very insecure and highly not recommended (because of that it's not provided here but can be easily found if required).

You can rewrite your SP to accept table as input parameter or rewrite it to output multiple rows, so then you can insert the values to temp table and use it within your query.

Comment: Thought of writing same

Comment: can I please get some sample to know how to accept table as input parameter? sorry I am new in sqlserver.

Comment: sure, here it is:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx